# Swiftmailer : The mailer "default" does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I have a Symfony 4.1 project and I would like to be able to send mails in dev environment but I have this error when I execute the command `php bin/console swiftmailer:email:send` :

> In NewEmailCommand.php line 76: The mailer "default" does not exist.

I think this is a problem with my configuration because I have the impression that it does not find the key of my default mailer in services.yaml.

[image: services.yaml]

packages/dev/swiftmailer.yaml :

```
swiftmailer:
    mailers:
        no_reply:
            delivery_address: test@yopmail.com
```

packages/swiftmailer.yaml :

```
swiftmailer:
    default_mailer: no_reply
    mailers:
        no_reply:
            url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
            spool: { type: memory }
```

BaseController.php :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace App\Controller;

use Swift_Mailer;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

abstract class BaseController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @var Swift_Mailer
     */
    protected $swiftMailer;

    public function __construct(Swift_Mailer $swiftMailer)
    {
        $this->swiftMailer           = $swiftMailer;
    }
}
```

All my controllers extend from BaseController.php

---

### UPDATE

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the Symfony package.
 *
 * (c) Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle;

/**
 * A console command for creating and sending simple emails.
 *
 * @author Gusakov Nikita <dev@nkt.me>
 */
class NewEmailCommand extends AbstractSwiftMailerCommand
{
    protected static $defaultName = 'swiftmailer:email:send';

    /** @var SymfonyStyle */
    private $io;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName(static::$defaultName) // BC with 2.7
            ->setDescription('Send simple email message')
            ->addOption('from', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'The from address of the message')
            ->addOption('to', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'The to address of the message')
            ->addOption('subject', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'The subject of the message')
            ->addOption('body', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'The body of the message')
            ->addOption('mailer', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'The mailer name', 'default')
            ->addOption('content-type', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'The body content type of the message', 'text/html')
            ->addOption('charset', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'The body charset of the message', 'UTF8')
            ->addOption('body-source', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'The source where body come from [stdin|file]', 'stdin')
            ->setHelp(
                <<<EOF
The <info>%command.name%</info> command creates and sends a simple email message.

<info>php %command.full_name% --mailer=custom_mailer --content-type=text/xml</info>

You can get body of message from a file:
<info>php %command.full_name% --body-source=file --body=/path/to/file</info>

EOF
            );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function initialize(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $this->io = new SymfonyStyle($input, $output);
        $this->io->title('SwiftMailer\'s Interactive Email Sender');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $mailerServiceName = sprintf('swiftmailer.mailer.%s', $input->getOption('mailer'));
        if (!$this->getContainer()->has($mailerServiceName)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('The mailer "%s" does not exist.', $input->getOption('mailer')));
        }

        switch ($input->getOption('body-source')) {
            case 'file':
                $filename = $input->getOption('body');
                $content = file_get_contents($filename);
                if (false === $content) {
                    throw new \Exception(sprintf('Could not get contents from "%s".', $filename));
                }
                $input->setOption('body', $content);
                break;
            case 'stdin':
                break;
            default:
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Body-input option should be "stdin" or "file".');
        }

        $message = $this->createMessage($input);
        $mailer = $this->getContainer()->get($mailerServiceName);
        $sentMessages = $mailer->send($message);

        $this->io->success(sprintf('%s emails were successfully sent.', $sentMessages));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function interact(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        foreach ($input->getOptions() as $option => $value) {
            if (null === $value) {
                $input->setOption($option, $this->io->ask(sprintf('%s', ucfirst($option))));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return $this->getContainer()->has('mailer');
    }

    /**
     * Creates new message from input options.
     *
     * @param InputInterface $input An InputInterface instance
     *
     * @return \Swift_Message New message
     */
    private function createMessage(InputInterface $input)
    {
        $message = new \Swift_Message(
            $input->getOption('subject'),
            $input->getOption('body'),
            $input->getOption('content-type'),
            $input->getOption('charset')
        );
        $message->setFrom($input->getOption('from'));
        $message->setTo($input->getOption('to'));

        return $message;
    }
}
```

The line 76 :

```
throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('The mailer "%s" does not exist.', $input->getOption('mailer')));
```

Output of

> php bin/console debug:container

[image]

Do you know where my problem may come from?

Comment: Can you update the question and add `NewEmailCommand.php` code please?

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: What is the output of `bin/console debug:container`?

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Which of the lines of `NewEmailCommand` is that line 76? If it checks for something in the container, which is obviously not configured to be in the container, what's the point in asking here instead of reconfiguring your application?

Comment: Sorry it's an oversight on my part for line 76. 
I'm asking here because I don't know how to solve my problem, otherwise I will try to solve it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Check the list of services listed by `php bin/console debug:container`, there is no service named `swiftmailer.mailer.default`, either use `swiftmailer.mailer` or `swiftmailer.mailer.no_reply`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error by

```
swiftmailer:
  default_mailer: default
  mailers:
    default:
      url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
      spool: { type: memory }
```